# A peculiar behavior of NSolve[]

Tags: equation-solving

```
NSolve[Power[x + 1, x + 1] - Power[x, x + 2] == 0, x, Reals]
```

returns:

> {{x -> 3.14104}}

Great.

However,

```
NSolve[Power[x + 1.5, x + 1.5] - Power[x, x + 3] == 0, x, Reals]
```

runs forever. :(

Now,

```
NSolve[Power[x + 2, x + 2] - Power[x, x + 4] == 0, x, Reals]
```

returns

> {{x -> 3.47175}}

Again great.

I expected "2.5" case would run forever, just like "1.5" case. But:

```
NSolve[Power[x + 2.5, x + 2.5] - Power[x, x + 5] == 0, x, Reals]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact
>   coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact
>   system and numericizing the result. >>

and outputs the answer:

> {{x -> 3.61691}}

---

*Since the solution is in real numbers, from numerical math point of view, all cases above are equal. Why such behavior of `NSolve[]` then?*

Comment: Your cases are not all equal.  Plot, for example, your two first cases: `Plot[{Power[x + 1, x + 1] - Power[x, x + 2], 
  Power[x + 1.5, x + 1.5] - Power[x, x + 3]}, {x, 0, 3.5}]` and you will see that the curves do not have the same shape.

Comment: @2012rcampion the curves are not literally equal, but they do not differ "topologically" if I may say

Comment: From numerical math point of view, they are almost the same, just one is steeper, and that should not be a problem for numerical algorithms for finding roots at all @2012rcampion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `NSolve` rather than just limiting x to `Reals`, limit it to a finite interval of interest, say 2 < x < 6

```
f[x_, a_] = Power[x + a, x + a] - Power[x, x + 2 a];

data = Table[
   {a, x /. NSolve[{f[x, a] == 0, 2 < x < 6}, x][[1]]},
   {a, 1/10, 10, 1/10}];

ListLinePlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"a", "root"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, two great ideas in one answer (restricting root interval, and plotting root behavior dependant on parameter a)!

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr Don't expect `NSolve` to give sensible results for equations with no analytic solution.**

If you are interested in a "numerical math point of view", use `FindRoot` or a related function to solve numerically.  `NSolve` tries to find a transformation to an equation it knows exact solutions for, then converts those solutions to machine-precision numbers when returning them.

For example, take the equation `x - Sin[x] == 1`:

```
NSolve[x - Sin[x] == 1, x]
(* NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve. >> *)

FindRoot[x - Sin[x] == 1, {x, 1}]
(* {x -> 1.93456} *)
```

Your equations look different to `NSolve`.  Note that it first converts approximate to exact numbers (hence the message "solving a corresponding exact system"), so that your troublesome equation is being treated as:

```
SetPrecision[Power[x + 1.5, x + 1.5] - Power[x, x + 3] == 0, Infinity]
```

$$
\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^{x+\frac{3}{2}}=x^{x+3}
$$

I don't know why `NSolve`/`Solve` get hung up on this particular equation, it probably makes a bad guess early on and misses the transformation it used on the other ones.

---

Just to demonstrate that Mathematica is handling your equations differently, we can look at the output of `Solve` instead of `NSolve`:

```
Solve[Power[x + 1, x + 1] - Power[x, x + 2] == 0, x, Reals]
```

$$
\text{Root}\left[\left\{(\text{$\#$1}+1)
   \left(\frac{\text{$\#$1}+1}{\text{$\#$1}}\right)^{\text{$\#$1}}-\text{$\#$1}^2\&,3.141\ldots\right\}\right]
$$

```
Solve[SetPrecision[Power[x + 2.5, x + 2.5] - Power[x, x + 5] == 0, 
  Infinity], x, Reals]
```

$$
\text{Root}\left[\left\{\frac{25 \sqrt{2 \text{$\#$1}+5} e^{\text{$\#$1} \log
   \left(\text{$\#$1}+\frac{5}{2}\right)-\text{$\#$1} \log (\text{$\#$1})}}{\text{$\#$1}^5}+\frac{20
   \sqrt{2 \text{$\#$1}+5} e^{\text{$\#$1} \log \left(\text{$\#$1}+\frac{5}{2}\right)-\text{$\#$1}
   \log (\text{$\#$1})}}{\text{$\#$1}^4}+\frac{4 \sqrt{2 \text{$\#$1}+5} e^{\text{$\#$1} \log
   \left(\text{$\#$1}+\frac{5}{2}\right)-\text{$\#$1} \log (\text{$\#$1})}}{\text{$\#$1}^3}-4
   \sqrt{2}\&,3.616\ldots\right\}\right]
$$

Very different results...